# Animation: fillEnable, fillBefore documentation contradiction; semantics including fillAfter

Tags: android, android-animation

Today I'm in the mood to get beyond trying out arbitrary permutations of boolean values for the attributes in question and understand what they really mean. ;)

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter%28boolean%29) turns out to be not very helpful, as it seems to contradict itself and is not too clear.

Let's have a look.

> [...] fillBefore [...] Defaults to true if setFillEnabled(boolean) *is not set to true*.
>
> If fillEnabled is true, the animation will apply the value of fillBefore. Otherwise, fillBefore is ignored [...]

So `fillBefore` *defaults to true* while being *ignored* at the same time if `fillEnabled` is *not true*? Or are we supposed to spot the subtle difference between *being* true and *being set to* true? But even that does not solve this mystery.

As if this was not enough, let's try to find out what is really controlled by these attributes.

> If fillBefore is true, this animation will apply its transformation before the start time of the animation.

So far, so good. But:

> If fillEnabled [...] [is false], fillBefore is ignored and the animation transformation is always applied until the animation ends.

What? So `fillEnabled` controls two aspects at the same time? Or how is *the animation transformation [...] always [being] applied until the animation ends* related to a single application of the animation before the starting time?

I will admit that I went along with these attributes very well until now, despite the documentation issues. But now I'm seeing a strange effect which I can't explain, so it's time to either dig into this deeper or find a workaround.

Has someone examined this systematically and/or can point me to an explanation? Didn't find much; in fact, people seem to avoid these attributes in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the documentation.

Chet Haase, of the Android UI Toolkit Team, has a nicer [explanation](http://graphics-geek.blogspot.com/2011/08/mysterious-behavior-of-fillbefore.html).

Comment: Great, thanks; just what I was looking for. Also, matches what I thought I knew so far (until I came across some oddity, but now I know I have to look somewhere else for its cause).